# network net_byfn id a4ebec5b9879b4dc72ac8abc3e6c03e183f1c50506473101431d1c7116e11657 has active endpoints

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I found an error after running `./byfn.sh down`. The error is

> ERROR: error while removing network: network net_byfn id
>   a4ebec5b9879b4dc72ac8abc3e6c03e183f1c50506473101431d1c7116e11657 has
>   active endpoints

I've gone through [./byfn.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/first-network/byfn.sh) but couldn't find where goes wrong.

The whole logs:

```
Stopping for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] 
proceeding ...
WARNING: The BYFN_CA1_PRIVATE_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The BYFN_CA2_PRIVATE_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Stopping cli                    ... done
Stopping orderer.example.com    ... done
Stopping peer1.org2.example.com ... done
Stopping peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Stopping peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Stopping peer1.org1.example.com ... done
Removing cli                    ... done
Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing peer1.org2.example.com ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Removing peer1.org1.example.com ... done
Removing network net_byfn
ERROR: error while removing network: network net_byfn id a4ebec5b9879b4dc72ac8abc3e6c03e183f1c50506473101431d1c7116e11657 has active endpoints
a17de78de306
fdcb06bbedbb
85be8e6a8c61
Untagged: dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-26c2ef32838554aac4f7ad6f100aca865e87959c9a126e86d764c8d01f8346ab:latest
Deleted: sha256:4d673a05f26c88b695930fda6c6483531e7e0821b81a19f597a5ea1da500623d
Deleted: sha256:1cfde5b8fc23484b83b759c2cdb9b8c9ef84fa30e76d91132a343d913431f332
Deleted: sha256:8a75adf4eb02dd9dc1f1ac0d55f1a232909632e050fb4a0accd8e1328b228951
Deleted: sha256:9d1f3186658704c1371375ec10d6054fd5d4b9e95e90e1a71ed7485c9e9c045b
Untagged: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0-384f11f484b9302df90b453200cfb25174305fce8f53f4e94d45ee3b6cab0ce9:latest
Deleted: sha256:651fbd69e9897382f605f9d9979399d514fdc2c8d91fb721115bbe1737fdae76
Deleted: sha256:c730e8afeb3c5f3a9c250d281c52a91db31952383f18656cd3382a5888302ddc
Deleted: sha256:fcbc20f614e902e6942e0dde76c36ddd7837a74ccfd8095b607bdf6fdafce930
Deleted: sha256:624b54e4c50ee27a9cadf4a29818717963cff9ba2080cce94ce6e050205a3052
Untagged: dev-peer0.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-15b571b3ce849066b7ec74497da3b27e54e0df1345daff3951b94245ce09c42b:latest
Deleted: sha256:ddf412a32bab3122b8d83323f67323e8f332e6d4bdbfd3cb1fc7840300f8dd67
Deleted: sha256:0b11b3428ac4e6bb5cb57cd274312a11544cb70d4fa91c3267e2f20f55f42e43
Deleted: sha256:12185610b4a12ca1b953f2639e8ea4ea978e9c2ab0d936171d1734a1f302dc71
Deleted: sha256:706af420f7b44218c3582a757102d377a74181474287182049c7573a592464a8
```

run `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

run `docker images -a`

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     1.4                 68914607b3a5        4 weeks ago         1.68GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     1.4.6               68914607b3a5        4 weeks ago         1.68GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     latest              68914607b3a5        4 weeks ago         1.68GB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          1.4                 3b96a893c1e4        5 weeks ago         150MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          1.4.6               3b96a893c1e4        5 weeks ago         150MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          latest              3b96a893c1e4        5 weeks ago         150MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       1.4                 0f9743ac0662        5 weeks ago         1.49GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       1.4.6               0f9743ac0662        5 weeks ago         1.49GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       latest              0f9743ac0662        5 weeks ago         1.49GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       1.4                 191911f4454f        5 weeks ago         1.36GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       1.4.6               191911f4454f        5 weeks ago         1.36GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       latest              191911f4454f        5 weeks ago         1.36GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     1.4                 84eaba5388e7        5 weeks ago         120MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     1.4.6               84eaba5388e7        5 weeks ago         120MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     latest              84eaba5388e7        5 weeks ago         120MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        1.4                 5a52faa5d8c2        5 weeks ago         128MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        1.4.6               5a52faa5d8c2        5 weeks ago         128MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        latest              5a52faa5d8c2        5 weeks ago         128MB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   0.4                 ede9389347db        4 months ago        276MB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   0.4.18              ede9389347db        4 months ago        276MB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   latest              ede9389347db        4 months ago        276MB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       0.4                 caaae0474ef2        4 months ago        270MB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       0.4.18              caaae0474ef2        4 months ago        270MB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       latest              caaae0474ef2        4 months ago        270MB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     0.4                 d369d4eaa0fd        4 months ago        261MB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     0.4.18              d369d4eaa0fd        4 months ago        261MB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     latest              d369d4eaa0fd        4 months ago        261MB
hyperledger/fabric-baseimage   amd64-0.4.18        9e353eca480f        4 months ago        1.3GB
```

run `docker volume ls`

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               net_orderer.example.com
local               net_peer0.org1.example.com
local               net_peer0.org2.example.com
local               net_peer1.org1.example.com
local               net_peer1.org2.example.com
```

docker version: 19.03.8

docker-compose version: 1.25.4

fabric version:1.4.6

Comment: Could you attach the content of `./byfn.sh`, please

Comment: Perhaps [byfn.sh](https://github.com/skcript/hyperledger-fabric-composer-multiorg-sample/blob/master/byfn.sh)

Answer (score 0):

The script is removing the containers and deleting the images.Have you checked the volumes.(`docker volume ls`).
Have you removed them manually.

You can do it using:

```
docker system prune
```

It will remove all the dangling images,containers.
If it does not fix the issue,remove all containers,images and volumes.
For removing volumes :

```
docker volume prune
```

Comment: Hi! Do you mean I need to remove the volumes manually? After running the `./byfn.sh down`, all the related docker containers were removed automatically. The docker images and volumes are listed out when I edited the question. You can have a look. I think the command `./byfn.sh down` should clear all the related material automatically but it throws an error. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah remove the volumes.It will work after that.I have updated my answer too.

Comment: Thanks!  But I think we should run `docker network prune`. I've found that [troubleshooting](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#troubleshooting).